# ¿Cambiamos el texto del botón: *Odio / Amo los sombreros* del Winter Bash?

Tags: discusión, winterbash

Con mucho respeto a quienes participan en este evento que se celebra anual e ininterrumpidamente desde 2014 (por lo que he podido [ver](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339891/%ef%b8%8f-winter-bash-2019-hat-list-%ef%b8%8f)). Mi planteamiento es simplemente para mostrar mi desacuerdo o disconformidad con el término usado en la traducción de las etiquetas de los botones que se usan para indicar si se desea participar o no en el evento denominado *Winter Bash*

---

**ODIO**

Citando [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org), en relación al significado de la palabra [odio](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odio):

> El odio es un intento por rechazar o eliminar aquello que nos genera disgusto; es decir, sentimiento de profunda antipatía, disgusto, aversión, enemistad o repulsión hacia una persona, cosa, o fenómeno, así como el deseo de evitar, limitar o destruir a su objetivo.
>
> El odio se puede basar en el miedo a su objetivo, ya sea justificado o no, o más allá de las consecuencias negativas de relacionarse con él. El odio se describe con frecuencia como lo contrario del amor o el afecto. El odio puede generar aversión, sentimientos de destrucción, destrucción del equilibrio armónico y ocasionalmente autodestrucción, aunque la mayoría de las personas puede odiar eventualmente a algo o alguien y no necesariamente experimentar estos efectos.
>
> El odio no es justificable desde el punto de vista racional porque atenta contra la posibilidad de diálogo y construcción común. Es posible que las personas sientan cierta aversión sobre personas u organizaciones, incluso ciertas tendencias ideológicas.
>
> El odio es una intensa sensación de desagrado. Se puede presentar en una amplia variedad de contextos, desde el odio de los objetos inanimados o animales, al odio de uno mismo u otras personas, grupos enteros de personas, la gente en general, la existencia, la sociedad, o todo. Aunque no siempre, el odio a menudo se asocia con sentimientos de enojo.

Claramente el *odio* es un sentimiento muy profundo o que connota una carga emocional profunda.

Y es por ello que no estoy de acuerdo en que el botón usado para indicar que no deseo participar en el evento *Winter Bash* tenga dicha palabra en su texto o etiqueta. Y es que el hecho de no desear participar en dicho evento, no indica que tenga yo un sentimiento tan profundo por los sombreros.

Entiendo que esto puede ser trivial, y seguramente algunos (como yo en su momento) simplemente no tomen en cuenta el significado de tal aseveración, o lo tomen a la ligera. Pero creo que más allá de ser simplemente una traducción de lo que refleja el sitio principal, la palabra *odio* de por sí tiene (IMHO) una carga un poco más profunda de su contraparte en inglés. O tal vez me equivoco.

---

**AMOR**

Nuevamente citando a Wikipedia, la palabra [amor](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amor) se define como:

> El amor es un concepto universal relativo a la afinidad entre seres, definido de diversas formas según las diferentes ideologías y puntos de vista (artístico, científico, filosófico, religioso). De manera habitual, y fundamentalmente en Occidente, se interpreta como un sentimiento relacionado con el afecto y el apego, y resultante y productor de una serie de actitudes, emociones y experiencias. En el contexto filosófico, el amor es una virtud que representa todo el afecto, la bondad y la compasión del ser humano. También puede describirse como acciones dirigidas hacia otros y basadas en la compasión, o bien como acciones dirigidas hacia otros (o hacia uno mismo) y basadas en el afecto.
>
> En español, la palabra amor (del latín, amor, -ōris) abarca una gran cantidad de sentimientos diferentes, desde el deseo pasional y de intimidad del amor romántico hasta la proximidad emocional asexual del amor familiar y el amor platónico,​ y hasta la profunda devoción o unidad del amor religioso. En este último terreno, trasciende del sentimiento y pasa a considerarse la manifestación de un estado del alma o de la mente, identificada en algunas religiones con Dios mismo o con la fuerza que mantiene unido el universo.
>
> Las emociones asociadas al amor pueden ser extremadamente poderosas, llegando con frecuencia a ser irresistibles. El amor en sus diversas formas actúa como importante facilitador de las relaciones interpersonales y, debido a su importancia psicológica central, es uno de los temas más frecuentes en las artes creativas (cine, literatura, música).

Aunque la palabra *amor* no connota nada negativo (al menos desde un punto de vista puritano o altruista), pienso en matices. Y es que el hecho de participar en el evento, no necesariamente indique que *ame* particularmente los sombreros, tal vez *ame* más el poder participar en el evento mismo.

Y es por eso que hago la pregunta aquí. Y de paso propongo lo siguiente:

Si se desea (por razones que pudiera entender claramente) seguir usando el par de palabras (antagónicas por convención) *amor/odio*, que no sea esta relacionada a los sombreros, sino mas bien al evento:

> *Odio el Winter Bash* / *Amo el Winter Bash*

O si se pudiese evitar el uso de dichas palabras, sería un simple:

> *Deseo (Quiero) participar* / *En otro momento (Tal vez luego)*

O directamente:

> *Participar* / *No participar*

Es mi inquietud sobre este tema, y aunque mi idea no es exigir, pedir, o demandar que se realice un cambio, sino llamar la atención sobre un hecho particular que me parece que puede tomarse como una imposición.

Y es que cada vez que se realice dicho evento, si no deseo participar, me veo haciendo clic en un botón que dice que *odio los sombreros*, lo cual no es cierto. Y si debo cambiar esta situación, debo hacer clic en un botón que dice que *amo los sombreros*, lo cual tampoco es cierto. Simplemente los sombreros me dan igual.

Cita:

> [Ok, here's the thing. Whitout any intention of polemize things. I'm not interested in participate of this Winter Bash thing. So, you gave me a very rude option that states that I hate hats. And that's not true. And if I want to revert that situation, you gave me the I love hats, which isn't true either](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53012607#53012607)

Comment: Vamos a poner dos respuestas para mostrar si se esta de acuerdo o no con este cambio

Comment: Bien visto. Yo no los odio, pero este año no me apetece jugar. Ni el año pasado los amaba, simplemente me divertía coleccionarlos. Supongo que es una traducción demasiado literal del love/hate tan usado en inglés.

Comment: mira si le vas a poner participar/no participar; que es esto? un banco? dejen circular la sangre por sus venas por favor, nadie deja de participar porque odie los sombreros

Answer (score 15):

Sí, estoy de acuerdo en cambiar los textos.

Comment: Amo esta propuesta :D

Comment: @fedorqui vamos a necesitar ideas para los nuevos textos (por como viene la mano ;) )

Answer (score 5):

No, prefiero dejar los textos como una traducción exacta

Answer (score 4):

Empiezo a odiar los sombreros porque no gano ninguno D':

Pienso que se debe dar mérito por intentarlo y modificar la etiqueta de odio por una nueva, sugiero: "**No me gustan los sombreros, prefiero bufandas**".