# Cambio en la ayuda de: ¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?

Tags: discusión

Este párrafo en ayuda de **¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?**:

> Busca, e investiga
> ...y mantén un registro de lo que encuentres. Incluso si no encuentras una respuesta útil en cualquier parte del sitio, incluyendo en los enlaces sobre preguntas relacionadas o que no hayan ayudado pueden ayudar a otros a entender cómo tu pregunta es diferente del resto.

Me parece esta mal redactado. según lo conversado en el sitio (chat) con otros [usuario](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5269/investigar-antes-de-preguntar#comment22941_5269) debería ser algo así:

> Busca, e investiga
> ... y agrega a tu post toda informacion relacionado a tu publicación que proporciones indicios de que realizaste previamente un exhaustiva investigación tanto en el Sitio o Internet de lo que encontraste. Incluso si no encuentras una respuesta útil en cualquier lugar, incluyendo los enlaces sobre preguntas relacionadas que no hayan ayudado, pueden ayudar a otros a entender cómo tu pregunta es diferente del resto. ten en cuenta que si tu publicación no cumple con este punto puede ser cerrada o recibir votos negativos.

Comment: por favor evita agregarme al menos que este totalmente de acuerdo con lo que decis.

Comment: yo no he dicho que vos estes de acuerdo...

Comment: Por eso.. evita nombrarme...

Comment: para mi, el verdadero problema no es añadir mas texto explicativo, es mas, si ya se lee poco, provocará que se lea menos

Comment: @gbianchi por que no he de nombrarte, si la sugerencia la hiciste voz, de que si me parecia que la ayuda estubiera incompleta que lo publicara en meta para que se edite ... esto fue tu idea ... ahora no quieres que lo diga?

Comment: @Nicolas en ese caso no tiene nada de malo agregar un parrafo nuevo... nadie notara el cambio

Comment: Yo te sugeri que si querias un cambio hicieras un post. No sugeri hacer el cambio ni nada de eso. Si no se entiende, voy a terminar editando yo el post.

Comment: no se que quieras editarle a la publicacion... estas en la libertad de hacerlo... igual siempre lo que haces es correcto...

Comment: Está bueno, quitaría algo de texto aquí y allá, pero aun así me gusta!

Comment: @DanteS. puedes agregar cual seria tu opción para presentar una mejor redacción, yo sugiero que las ayudas sean lo mas explicitas posibles y evitar dejar lo menos posible al usuario la interpretación ... ya que una interpretación puede variar de persona en persona..

Comment: Y ahi donde dije que esto era lo que habia que poner? cuando una persona te dice que no la refieras, que quites referencias hacia ella, o que no la pongas en el medio, lo haces y no protestas. Si no lo haces, va en contra de las reglas del sitio y la politica de se amable. No hay mas vueltas que darle al asunto...

Comment: Pensaba dejar una respuesta, pero al final me sentí inseguro. No importa :c

Comment: Mucho texto, ya está bien como está ahora.

Answer (score 5):

Tampoco estoy de acuerdo en este cambio al texto de ayuda en [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) por los siguientes motivos:

1. **Tiende a ser impositiva**

Cuando dices (no se corrige acentuación ni otros errores gramaticales u ortográficos):

> y agrega a tu post toda informacion relacionado a tu publicación que proporciones indicios de que realizaste previamente un exhaustiva investigación tanto en el Sitio o Internet de lo que encontraste.

¿Porqué debo agregar a mi Post toda información que haya realizado previamente como indicio de que lo he hecho? ¿Acaso eso es un punto obligatorio para realizar una pregunta en el sitio?

Tal como está redactado actualmente es una sugerencia de cómo realizar una buena pregunta, pero en ningún caso es obligatorio.

Si leemos detenidamente el inicio del texto del artículo: [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) vemos que en todo momento se habla de **sugerencias o consejos**, y en todo caso **no es una plantilla a seguir a [rajatabla](https://dle.rae.es/rajatabla)**:

> Para mejorar tus oportunidades de obtener una respuesta, acá hay algunos consejos:

2. **El texto que dices que está mal redactado es una traducción del sitio en inglés, del cual somos una versión en castellano**

No estoy seguro de si los textos de ayuda de [Stackoverflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) pueden llegar a ser diferentes de los textos de [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). Si ese fuera el caso, no le veo entonces sentido a la herramienta de traducción del sitio.

El texto en inglés dice:

> Search, and research... and keep track of what you find. Even if you don't find a useful answer elsewhere on the site, including links to related questions that haven't helped can help others in understanding how your question is different from the rest.

Suponiendo que los cambios en el apartado del centro de ayuda se hacen en el sitio en inglés, para que sean adoptados en las distintas versiones existentes en la red SE, entonces esta propuesta deberías hacerla en Meta del sitio en inglés.

3. **Imponiendo un esquema no ayudas realmente a que una persona desarrolle su total capacidad**

Mucho debate ha habido sobre el sistema educativo a nivel mundial, donde más que moldear al ser, se le impone un esquema, sin realmente motivarle a pensar o desarrollar su creatividad para mejorar. En casi todas tus participaciones en el chat, hablas de que los usuarios más veteranos (no sé si te refieres a reputación o años) ahuyentan a los usuarios nuevos mediante la acción de voto en contra, cierre de pregunta e incluso documentación incompleta o poco clara en el sitio.

Las personas que llegan en busca de información a Stackoverflow, lo hacen de acuerdo a sus propias necesidades, dudas, inquietudes, etc. Muchos se registran para hacer sólo 1 pregunta en toda su vida como desarrolladores y eso es una decisión personal. El registrarse en el sitio es voluntario, el participar con respuestas es voluntario, el editar una pregunta de acuerdo a las sugerencias recibidas (sean enlaces o comentarios directos) también es voluntario. No todos los que se registran en Stackoverflow desean participar activamente en la comunidad, no se les puede obligar y en muchos casos no se les puede ni siquiera persuadir a que lo hagan, lo harán de acuerdo a sus propios criterios.

Decir que a *todos* los usuarios nuevos se les trata mal es una falacia. Decir que un usuario sin experiencia en el sitio se siente atormentado por la falta de *empatía* en el sitio es también una falacia.

A los usuarios nuevos se les guía a través de las herramientas que el sitio tiene para ello: el recorrido de bienvenida y los diferentes textos del centro de ayuda. No existe un *departamento de atención y guía al nuevo usuario*. Cada quién irá creciendo en el sitio de acuerdo a lo que su capacidad, necesidad y deseo le indiquen.

Si se impone un esquema de funcionamiento estricto del sitio, al contrario de incentivar la participación la estarás desmotivando. Me imagino los comentarios de posibles nuevos usuarios ante un sistema impuesto:

> *No me atrevo a exponer una pregunta en SOes porque te piden más requisitos que una entidad bancaria para un préstamo hipotecario.*

> *Cuando vayas a preguntar a SOes ten a mano el compendio completo de la especificación del lenguaje, ya que es requisito añadirlo en tu pregunta como prueba de que has investigado*

La idea no es responder y ayudar a todos sin miramiento, la idea es crear contenido de calidad y para ello se debe desechar el contenido de baja calidad. En el proceso se votará en contra, se cerrarán preguntas y se motivará a leer los textos del sitio para que el usuario nuevo mejore su publicación. Si no estás de acuerdo con esta forma o modelo de Stackoverflow entonces tal vez no deberías participar en el sitio. No con esto te estoy diciendo que te vayas, al contrario, al responder a tus preguntas te hago partícipe de un debate válido y con respeto. Esta respuesta es sólo mi opinión a tu propuesta, y pone de manifiesto el cómo la comunidad participa de manera activa en la mejora de la funcionalidad del sitio.

Intentar responder todas y cada una de las preguntas que se formulen no es parte del modelo de Stackoverflow, tampoco imponer una plantilla única, irrevocable y exclusiva para realizar una pregunta, porque no existe tal tipo de preguntas. En [otra publicación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5280/mejoras-en-las-herramientas-funcionalidades-del-sitio) (posterior a esta) has formulado tu idea de hacer el Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable de uso obligatorio en una pregunta, y aunque parece a *priori* un idea excelente, no puede ser aplicada debido a que existen preguntas netamente teóricas o de lenguaje agnóstico que son válidas en el sitio, pero que por causa de este requisito quedarían excluidas.

En todo caso, la propuesta de poner anuncios, banners, carteles y mucho texto, al final termina siendo contraproducente.

En esta interfaz llena de *sugerencias*, *noticias*, *etc*, se pierde de vista el propósito del motor de búsqueda:

[image: Landing page Yahoo!]

En cambio en esta otra, mucho más limpia, se enfatiza la acción. Es casi como si te dijera: *Vamos, pregunta*.

[image: Landing page Google]

Para finalizar, y adelantándome a lo que seguramente vas a preguntarme, en lo personal no estoy buscando una propuesta de mejora en el sitio o en el sistema (creo que esto último es mucho más difícil lograr) actualmente. Tampoco tengo propuestas propias sobre los temas que has tocado en tus publicaciones. Cuando he tenido propuestas las he manifestado en mis propias preguntas en Meta, por ejemplo esta propuesta fue bien aceptada por la comunidad: [¿Cambiamos el texto del botón: *Odio / Amo los sombreros* del Winter Bash?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4496/cambiamos-el-texto-del-bot%c3%b3n-odio-amo-los-sombreros-del-winter-bash)

Y aunque sí, me siento cómodo en el sitio tal como funciona actualmente, he adoptado los cambios aprobados por la comunidad sin problema alguno. Seguramente algún día una de tus propuestas sea bien recibida y se realice el cambio, y yo tan a gusto me adaptaré al mismo. De esto trata Meta.

Comment: ok. gracias por tu respuesta. lo tomare en cuenta.